# How to get string between starting with X to ending with Y using Shell

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, string

I have dynamic string which are mentioned below, where I want to get `ABCXXX.XXX.XXX` string till `,` character. Starting character is fix `(ABC)`CAPITAL ONLY  and ending also fix `com` or `Xcom`.

String can be like :

```
S1= "10.10.10.10 (XXXX,ABC123.sub.domain.Xcom,XXX,XX - abc123 ) ANY
S2= "10.10.10.10 (ABC567.subd.domain.com, - ) ANY
```

Output want :

```
S1= ABC123.sub.domain.com
S2= ABC567.subd.domain.Xcom
```

I tried :

```
 $1=ABC  # argument
 echo $S1| grep -o -P '(?=<$1).*(?=com,)'
```

Output get :

```
123.sub.domain.X   # But it should be ABC123.sub.domain.Xcom
```

Can anyone help to cut it with shell script?

Comment: The assignments shouldn't have spaces after them, and there appears to be an unbalanced double-quote...? Are these variable assignments or literal lines in a file?

Comment: Wouldn't S1's result end in ".Xcom", and S2's result be ".com"?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I updated question, i want output from "ABC" to "com" (both are include) like ABC123.sub.domain.Xcom. note : line contains also same hostname

Comment: Copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net, fix the issues it tells you about, and then post the fixed code if you still have a problem you'd like help with.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this works for you.

```
$ S1= "10.10.10.10 (XXXX,ABC123.sub.domain.Xcom,XXX,XX - abc123 ) ANY
$ echo $S1 | grep -o "ABC.*com" 
ABC123.sub.domain.Xcom
```